# Is creating a cache file for every user efficient?

Tags: php, caching

So we're on the same page, I'm building a PHP class to do a username lookup from Mojang using their web service `https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/`. I want to cache the results I get for an hour however, I need to do this for thousands of users. The way I have it set up now is that the class creates a cache file for every request I do. Once I put this in production, thousands of files will be generating which I'm not sure is very efficient.

1. Is this an efficient way?
2. Is this going to cause any performance issues over time.
3. If it isn't efficient, would it be good to delete all cache files daily?

The class isn't big, I wrote it in an hour.

```
class Player {
    private $_uuid,
            $_username;

    private function fetch($id) {
        $query = 'https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/' . $id;

        if(file_exists('core/classes/cache/'. $id .'.cache') && (filemtime('core/classes/cache/'. $id .'.cache') > (time() - 60 * 60 ))) {
            // Less than 60 minutes, pull from cache

            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('core/classes/cache/'. $id .'.cache'));


        } else {
            // Over 60 minutes, fetch and store to cache



            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($query));
            file_put_contents('core/classes/cache/'. $id .'.cache', json_encode($data));


        }



            $this->_username = $data->name;

            return $this->_username;

    }

    public function username($uuid) {
        return $this->fetch($uuid);
    }
```

So this works out fine, it returns what is needed and creates the cache file successfully. What do you guys think? Is there a better way to cache this information?

Usage:

```
$user = new Player;

echo $user->username('c3fed4d91c024fb89bf1cb0166aa9104');
```

Returns `Wingzzz (Username of this id)`

Creates a cache file named `c3fed4d91c024fb89bf1cb0166aa9104.cache` with the json object stored in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into an in-memory caching system like [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). This is a far better and faster solution that won't consume disk space.

You could also implement a system where each cached item has a very short life span, but every time the user visits the site, the lifespan is extended (users who go to the site once and leave won't have their cached data sitting in memory for extended periods of time, but users who are staying on the site won't have to wait for their data to be fetched, as it remains in cache).

While memcached is probably the easiest system to setup, you could also setup Redis which has richer data structured. Memcached only supports flat values, but you can `json_encode` whatever you want to store in it.

---

As for your disk based system, it's probably going to be fine if you don't have too many users. The primary concern would be disk IO performance and storage, depending on the size of the files. You could implement a cron job to clean up these files every hour if they are older than an hour.

You may want to look into storing the data using PHP sessions, which automatically deleted after a certain period of time by PHP, and are stored on the filesystem. It would make your implementation easier.

---

Finally, you may want to look into not storing the data at all. Instead, why not set cookies for the data you want to store, and have the client transmit you all the data you need? You'd have to use a system like signatures with [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) to verify your data hasn't been tampered with, but this way has the least impact on your server.

Comment: It seems feasible to run a cron job to delete all files in the cache directory as these cache files are relatively small. How would I set up this cron job? I've never made one before on my server.

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) about how Linux crons work. Basically you add an entry to your crontab that either calls a PHP cleanup script or a bash command that does the clean for you, its pretty easy. If you're on a shared hosting provider, you'll probably have to use your control panel to do it. cPanel/Plesk support crons.